# Run a script to load commands into my main script

Tags: powershell

I have a powershell file that I have downloaded from ScriptCenter that allows me to control and query virtual desktops on my machine (https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Powershell-commands-to-d0e79cc5).

Using their example, I can run that ps1 file at the start of my script to use those commands that the script creates.  All fine here.

The only issue with this is that when I run my script, it asks to confirm to run it.  This is something I don't want my script to do.

To work around this, I tried using the "PowerShell" command with "-ExecutionPolicy Bypass" set.  This removes the prompt to approve the script, however it stops the script from being loaded into my scripts session as I can't use any of the commands it make available by running it.

How do I either run the script first, without it prompting, or execute the powershell command so that it is run in the session space of my script so that its commands are available?

Thanks

Comment: Dot source the script `. myscript.ps1` instead of calling powershell.exe.

Comment: @EBGreen, thanks.  I didn't actually think the PS file that I was loading was actually unblocked, but turns out it was.  I unblocked it through windows explorer and all good now.